# Prove that the language L = {w1, w1w2, w1w2w3, ..} is regular, provided wi is in a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Let's assume that we're working over a finite alphabet $\Sigma=\{a, b\}$. How can one prove that $$L_2=\{w_1w_2...w_m| m ∈ \mathbb{N}, ∀i(w_i ∈ L)\}$$ is a regular language, provided that L is regular? By the way, L is a fixed language in the problem that I am solving, but it's regularity is trivial to prove so I have omitted it. This next step, however, I can't think of a valid way to prove. I would be glad if you guys could give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your language is known as $L^+$.

It is a very standard property of regular languages that if $L$ is regular then so is $L^*$; this can be proved in several ways, and you can find proofs in textbooks and online sources. Since $L^+$ is either equal to $L^*$ or obtained from it by removing $\epsilon$ (the empty string), then $L^+$ is also regular.

Comment: Oh god. I was looking at some more complex constructions the whole day and been overthinking it. Thank you!